SQL Server Row_Number() sequence not skipping NULL or 0 values to calculate working days
I am attempting to create a Working Days field in an existing date dimension in SQL Server to extract the nth working day of a month. I have researched solutions so far and have created a field for Working Day where weekend days= 0 and Weekdays=1. I have used Row_Number () to generate a sequence to indicate the nth working day. However my issue is Row_Number () sequence isn't calculating as expected as it doesn't skip the 0 values and continues sequence. Anyone have an ideas to fix? Thank you.
SELECT 
    DATE_KEY_YYYYMM,
    [Date KEY],
    [Day of Week Short Name],
    [Day of Week Number],
    CASE 
        WHEN [Day of Week Number] IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS BusinessDay,
    CASE 
        WHEN [Day of Week Number] IN (6, 7) 
            THEN NULL 
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date_Key_YYYYMM] ORDER BY [Date Key]) 
    END AS [RowCount]
FROM
    [DIM].[Call Date]

Output



Date Key YYYY
Date
Day of Week
WorkingDay
RowCount




201404
20140401
Tues
1
1


201404
20140402
Wed
1
2


201404
20140403
Thurs
1
3


201404
20140404
Fri
1
4


201404
20140405
Sat
0
NULL


201404
20140406
Sun
0
NULL


201404
20140407
Mon
1
7



Correct output - I need this:



Date Key YYYY
Date
Day of Week
WorkingDay
RowCount




201404
20140401
Tues
1
1


201404
20140402
Wed
1
2


201404
20140403
Thurs
1
3


201404
20140404
Fri
1
4


201404
20140405
Sat
0
NULL


201404
20140406
Sun
0
NULL


201404
20140407
Mon
1
5




a quick hack is to change the order by to: ORDER BY WorkingDay DESC, Date perhaps

You need to put your NULL values in a different partition. Just because you aren't displaying the value of ROW_NUMBER doesn't mean its not calculated. If you have a book, and tear out pages 5 & 6, that doesn't make the page number printed on page 7 now show as 5; it's still page 7.

can you include the sample data that is used to retrieve the deisred output

@GuidoG I'd suggest we have that, in truth. It's either markdown table with the WorkingDay and RowCount columns excluded. None of the other columns are manipulated, and no columns that aren't exposed are used in expressions.

@siggemannen thanks for the hack. Tried and its work, so in theory I could use that solution and join onto the main dimension table to avoid any sorting issues?

Can you create a minimal reproducible example using a SQL fiddle, or at least a minimalistic script that reproduces the issue? We would need: 1. sample tables 2. sample sequence 3. sample data

Why is this calculated instead of stored in the dimension table? That's what dimension tables are for. That's what allows indexing those fields to speed up queries by eg working day

@Panagiotis Kanavas the intension is store in the dimension table to make this more efficient, its just currently missing at the moment. Need the ability to select the Nth working day to automate some of our jobs.

In that case store the BusinessDay field first with eg UPDATE DimDate Set BusinessDay=IIF(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) IN (1,7),0,1)) and then calculate the count. This will make it easier to calculate the number with SUM(Businessday) OVER(...)

It might be a more intuitive solution to simply do what you're saying: skip the calculation for rows that aren't business days, but use SUM() OVER(). e.g.:
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT [Date Key YYYY], [Date], [Day of Week],
    BusinessDay = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) IN (1,7) 
                  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM [Date Dim]
)
SELECT [Date Key YYYY], [Date], [Day of Week], BusinessDay, 
    [RowCount] = CASE WHEN BusinessDay = 1 THEN SUM(BusinessDay)
                 OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) END
FROM src;

Output:



Date Key YYYY
Date
Day of Week
BusinessDay
RowCount




201404
2014-04-01
Tues
1
1


201404
2014-04-02
Wed
1
2


201404
2014-04-03
Thurs
1
3


201404
2014-04-04
Fri
1
4


201404
2014-04-05
Sat
0
null


201404
2014-04-06
Sun
0
null


201404
2014-04-07
Mon
1
5




Example db<>fiddle

(I didn't need the PARTITION BY given the sample data, but you'd add it if you need it.)
Though some suggestions:

Why are you calculating business day (and count of business days) in your queries? This could be a simple computed column in the dimension table. Or manually applied exactly once, since weekdays never change, but also, you might want to account for government holidays, business closures, etc.

Try to avoid keywords (like Date) and names that otherwise violate rules for identifiers.



The table name DATE_KEY_YYYYMM is scary. Why are there so many questions lately about tables name whatever_2024_10_08 ?

Thanks @Aaron Bertrand for the feedback. Will definitely take this on board. This solution works perfectly. I tested incorporating Bank Holidays and works great. The intention is to put this into an existing dimension table, just struggled to get the code working. Main use case for this is to help automate a data freeze in line with a contract requirements.
